# Finding midpoint of a cluster of points (2D)

Tags: geometry

Probably the dumbest question of the day, but given a cluster of points on a 2D graph, to find the "average" coordinate that sits at the midpoint of the cluster, is it as simple as averaging each coordinate (ave x-coord, ave y-coord)? Would this give me the same point as optimizing for minimum distance between midpoint and all other points summed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no.  This minimizes the absolute value of the vector sum of the components (which allows for $0$ to be the minimum).  You want to minimize the average of the differences squared (for a euclidean norm) which will be non-zero in general.  I would think this is related to a least squares fit.

Comment: I'd say no. Imaging 3 collinear points $A$, $B$, and $C$ so that $AB$ < $BC$. The midpoint $P$ by averaging lies on $BC$. The sum of the distances is $AC+BP$. However, you can further optimize this distance by placing the midpoint at $B$, where the sum of the distances is $AC$.

Comment: Did you find a formula to do this?